# Can you undo a difficulty change in The Witcher 2?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, the-witcher-2

I'm going after the "Madman" achievement which entails completing the game on "Dark" difficulty. I accidentally changed the difficulty from Dark to Normal. I then loaded an autosave from earlier thinking that maybe the difficulty would be back at Dark, and it was! If I keep playing from that save, will I still get the achievement? I'm just not sure if somehow it will still recognize that I went to normal, and I would rather not play through on Dark mode and not get the achievement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you played on darkmode and saved, like you said, you should be fine. As long as in your savegame you didn't switch difficulties then you shouldn't worry.